# MFC, Is there any handy way to get the contents of an edit box within its member function?

Tags: mfc, cedit

I'm customizing an edit box by inheriting a new class from `CEdit` based on MFC. And I suppose to access its contents (text) inside its member funtions. I wonder if there is any handier/safer/faster way to read and write the string, than calling the public funtion `GetWindowText()`?

Comment: What's not 'handy' about the `GetWindowText()` and `SetWindowText()` member functions?

Comment: I need to create an extra string, then copy it...emmm, I thought the window class could leave a backdoor to its own member functions...

Comment: IIRC, the `CWnd::GetWindowText()` member function is just a wrapper for the global `::GetWindowText(hWnd, lpString, strlen)` API routine. The MFC window-based classes don't really have any 'special' privileges/access to the native, underlying `HWND` object.

Comment: Got it, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a single-line edit control the only way to get to the text stored in the control is to call [`GetWindowText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowtextw) (after an optional call to [`GetWindowTextLength`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowtextlengthw)). MFC's `CWnd` implementation provides two [`GetWindowText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class#getwindowtext) overloads, one of which taking a reference to a `CString`. This overload certainly meets the *"handy"* and *"safe"* categories by taking on the responsibility of managing memory for you. As for *"fast"*, well, heap allocations are inherently costly; the actual copy itself is blazingly fast.

Multi-line edit controls provide additional APIs to directly access the in-memory representation of the control's text. The edit control messages [`EM_GETHANDLE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-gethandle) and [`EM_SETHANDLE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-sethandle) allow a client to gain read-only access to the text or change the memory location used by the control to store its text, respectively. They are exposed as the `CEdit` member functions [`GetHandle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cedit-class#gethandle) and [`SetHandle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cedit-class?view=msvc-170#sethandle).

The MFC documentation for either suggests that the [`DS_LOCALEDIT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/dialog-box-styles) dialog style were required for them to work. While that may have been the case in 16-bit Windows, I don't believe this is true today.